# How to change configuration using branches in Bamboo yaml specs?

Tags: yaml, bamboo

I want to change some parameters in my bamboo plan using branches.

For example:

I want to create Bamboo plan with different branches and each branch should have different job or task.

Is it possible to override some parameters using one yaml file configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that was finally used: **branch-overrides** key

```
branch-overrides:
  - custom-new-branch:
      stages:
        - Build: *build
      variables: *variables
      repositories: *repositories
      triggers: *triggers
      labels: *labels
```

Comment: How does this answer the requirement that "each branch should have different job or task"?

Comment: Using branch-overrides key you can configure each bamboo branch you have created. It is not a best solution, but it can be used to change task or stages

Comment: Where is this option: is it only a yaml feature because I can't see such a thing on the UI? Can you also point to some documentation perhaps?

Comment: Yes, its yaml feature. You can find detailed information here
https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/8.2.1/specs.html?yaml#overriding-branch-settings-using-bamboo-specs

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about this feature. Shame on Bamboo for not supporting it with the UI or JavaSpecs!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Your only way forward is to use https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/conditional-tasks-in-bamboo-1077907046.html so that you enable some tasks to run on some branch builds.

Comment: I want to have different parameters for agent (Requirements) in my bamboo branches.

Comment: Not possible. Afaik.